# Javascript - Why calling function defined inside a closour?

Tags: javascript, global-object

I have seen many js frameworks (including jquery) using closure around their main function scope. For example,

```
var obj = (function(){
    return {
        test : function(){
            alert('test');
        }
    }
})();
obj.test()
```

jquery source,
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js

Whats the need that extra 'closure' around the 'function'? Or whats the difference if we are using it like,

```
var obj = function(){
    return {
        test : function(){
            alert('test');
        }
    }
}();
obj.test()
```

Both have the same behavior and function definition itself puts all the local variable inside a new scope... so why the extra closure?

Comment: The two pieces of code you posted are equivalent.

Comment: You seem to mean "parentheses" and not "closures".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645766/why-are-parenthesis-used-to-wrap-a-javascript-function-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It adds the "big"object\library functions, and not adding them to the global object.

The two options you pasted are just like the difference between:

```
var foo = (2);
var foo = 2;
```

*No difference...*

---

**Update:**

Now I undersatnd your question, **parentheses** don't create new scope in javascript, only functions.

Comment: @gdoron I thought he is asking why not just `var obj = {
        test : function(){
            alert('test');
        }
    };`

Answer (score 0):

That is just a convention to be able to easily distinguish self-executing functions from normal functions.