# declaring and defining functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a doubt regarding functions(objects) in javascript.
I have 2 pieces of code like,

```
    var a= function(){
    console.log('abc')
     }
```

and

```
     var a= (function(){
     console.log('abc')
     })
```

what is the difference between these two>>
thanx:)

Comment: No difference whatsoever. The parenthesis aren't doing anything useful there. You could do `(((function(){})))` and it'll still be the same thing, unless what you mean is `(function(){}())`...

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645766/why-are-parenthesis-used-to-wrap-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: @theintersect - That question is asking about immediately invoked function expressions. There is no invokation of the function in this question.

Comment: indeed, but it is very helpful when he does invoke. http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens. But thanks for that, i may have overlooked his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical difference. They will both result in an anonymous function being assigned to `a`.

The first is a "[simple assignment](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.1)". In the second, the parentheses are acting as a "[grouping operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.6)", which does one thing:

> The production *PrimaryExpression : ( Expression )* is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Return the result of evaluating Expression. This may be of type Reference.

So the grouping operator will return the function contained within it, and assign it to `a`, just like the first example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference now, but if you add another parenthesis () after second function it will run function without invocation.

```
 var a= (function(){
     console.log('abc')
     })()
```

it will print 'abc' straightaway

Comment: You will also be able to do 

var a= function(){
     console.log('abc')
}()

So I think there is no difference there as well. The only subtle difference I know of is in the requirement of a function name. See my answer if you're interested.

Comment: Also nice to know that in this case you would not get the reference to a, you need to explicitly return some value

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You have a function expression, and you can put any number of parentheses around an expression.

Just as this:

```
a = 42;
```

is the same as this:

```
a = (42);
```

and this:

```
a = (((((42)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference.

( and ) constitute a grouping. A grouping can only contain an expression, thus any function inside it will be an expression and not a declaration.

Since ECMA specifies that a function declaration must always have a function name, and a function expression may omit it, you will be able to do the following

```
(function() {});
```

while the following declaration is not valid

```
function() {};
```

It won't matter that often, but still... Read this in-depth article for more: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, the two examples you've given are essentially the same.

This question has a lot more information contained in the answers regarding parentheses usage, might be worth your time to spin through!

[Why are parenthesis used to wrap a javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645766/why-are-parenthesis-used-to-wrap-a-javascript-function-call)