# Closure in Javascript (Simple)

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm very new to programming and have a quick question regarding a demonstration of closure given here: http://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook?t=27m19s.

The code is:

```
var digit_name = function () {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
    return function (n) {
        return names[n];
    };
} ();

alert(digit_name(3));
```

My question is: Why is there an additional `();` outside of the function `digit_name`? Are we calling the anonymous secondary function? I ran it without the `();` and it came back with `" function (n) {return names[n];} "`. I would really appreciate a description of what happens to the parameter 3 when you pass it to the function digit_name, since that function doesn't have a specified parameter.

I apologize if I'm asking a basic question or using incorrect terminology. I've looked into a few related questions but alas, to no avail! Thank you in advance to those kind enough to provide a well-fashioned answer.

Comment: Those are not supposed to be there....

Comment: "()" are there to actually call the function to get `digit_name = <result of calling the function>`

Comment: Of course, don't forget to the read the StackOverflow explanation of [Javascript Closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do empty parentheses () after a function declaration do in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422026/what-do-empty-parentheses-after-a-function-declaration-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In that code](http://jsfiddle.net/9t4v8/), it makes the outer function [execute immediately](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), thus returning the inner function as `digit_name`. But since the returned function carries a reference to `names`, the scope of the outer function does not terminate like it normally should. Thus, the scope lives and it becomes a closure.

It's like doing:

```
function anon() {
  var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
  return function (n) {
    return names[n];
  };
}

var digit_name = anon();

alert(digit_name(3));
```

So when you call `digit_name()`, you are actually calling the *returned inner function* which carries it's own `names`.

I suggest you read about [closures at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). I also have [an article](http://scratchpaper.tk/blog/understanding-javascript-closures-like-a-fish-tank/) discussing about closures in simple terms.